# python 3.6 bug or i am nuts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

checks if items in a list are consecutive.

```
[True for x in lst[:-1] for y in lst[1:] if x + 1 == y]
```

so list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
returns `[True, True, True, True]` meaning that list is consecutive.

list `[1,2,3,4,4]` 
returns `[True, True, True, True]` meaning that list is consecutive, but it's not.

doing for each statement proves that

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,4]


def consecutive(lst):    
    lst.sort()
    return [True for x in lst[:-1] for y in lst[1:] if x + 1 == y]


print(consecutive(lst))

some_list = []
for i,j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]):
    if i+1 == j:
        some_list.append(True)
    else:
        some_list.append(False)

print(some_list)
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: i simply copied your code n ran and got the result what you're expecting

Comment: what did you run it on anaconda?

Comment: issue is that code is doing same thing one by using list-comprehension and another using "for statement " but output is different

Comment: A list comprehension `[True for ...]` cannot possibly return anything other than a list full of `True`s - where could any other value come from?  The problem is that you aren't iterating over `lst[:-1]` and `lst[1:]` in parallel (you'd need `zip()` to do that), you're looping over every pair of values from the list - any instance where N and N+1 both exist somewhere in the list results in a `True`.

Comment: FWIW you can simplify the whole `if i+1 == j: ...` block to `some_list.append(i+1 == j)`, which then easily converts to a comprehension `some_list = [i+1 == j for i, j in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list comprehension is doing nested loops, not parallel loops. It's looping over the cross product of the two slices. You can see this if you remove the `if` and return the values of `x` and `y` themselves.

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in lst[:-1] for y in lst[1:]]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 4)]
```

The result contains `True` whenever the paired elements are consecutive; when they're not consecutive it doesn't add anything to the result. There are 4 pairs that are consecutive, so that's what you get in the result.

If you want to test only adjacent elements, use `zip()` in the comprehension:

```
>>> [True for x, y in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]) if x + 1 == y]
[True, True, True]
```

If you want to return both `True` and `False` in the list, you shouldn't use `if`, you should return the result of the test:

```
>>> [(x + 1 == y) for x, y in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])]
[True, True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing.

I tweaked it a bit and here's what happened:

```py
>>> [[x, y] for x in lst[:-1] for y in lst[1:]]
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 4], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 4]]
```

Your list comprehension is actually a 2D loop and you're just filtering all the combinations for a semi-random number of `True`'s back.

In your case, `[1, 2]`, `[2, 3]`, `[3, 4]`, and `[3, 4]` are satisfying the condition `x + 1 == y`.

Consider rewriting `consecutive`, here's a quick idea for example:

```py
def consecutive(lst):
    return [lst[i] + 1 == lst[i + 1] for i in range(len(lst) - 1)]
    # implicitly does the same thing as return [True if lst[i] + 1 == lst[i + 1] else False for i in range(len(lst) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the first function as the following:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,4]


def consecutive(lst):    
    lst.sort()
    return [True if lst[:-1][i] +1 ==lst[1:][i] else False  for i,x in enumerate(lst[:-1])  ]  

print(consecutive(lst))
[True, True, True, False]
```

This shows that the first three elements are consecutive.
If you just want the consecutive pairs as set to `True` use the following code:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,4]


def consecutive(lst):    
    lst.sort()
    return [True for i,x in enumerate(lst[:-1]) if lst[:-1][i] +1 ==lst[1:][i]   ]


print(consecutive(lst))
[True, True, True]
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. The first one is supposed to be [True, True, True, False], same as the second one re @wjandrea

Comment: @notacorn In the original code he did not use `False` for the first function. So I think he is asking why it shows four `True` although it has three consecutive pairs. Anyway I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You really only need ONE iteration to accomplish this

See Code Below:

```py
def consecutive(list_):
    n = len(list_)
    list_.sort()
    ans = [True if list_[i-1]+1 == list_[i] else False for i in range(1,n)]
    return ans
```

```py
list_ = [2,5,1,2,6,3,7,7]
print(consecutive(list_))
```

```
[True, False, True, False, True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[True  if(lst[x]+1 == lst[x+1])  else False for x in range(len(lst)-1)]
```